# What is the principle of sumproduct function in Excel?

Tags: excel

This function can also calculate something like the result of sumifs if I put an array into the criteria argument: =sumproduct(sumifs(sumrange, criteria range, criteria)). It gives me the sum of the sum of all the criterion in the array. If I just do =sumifs(sumrange,criteria range, criteria) and the criterion is an array, then the result would be zero. I could only check the result by pressing F9 and it gives me the sum of each criteria separately. Why can sumproduct function add up all the separate values here?

Comment: fwiw, your sumifs could also be `=sum(sumifs(sumrange, criteria range, criteria))`

Comment: No, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

When you use this formula

`=SUMIFS(sumrange,criteria range, criteria)`

with a range in place of the criteria then the result is an array of values

To get the result you want you can enclose that in `SUM` function......but then the formula needs to be "array entered" with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.....so using `SUMPRODUCT` is a way to avoid array entry. Because the result of `SUMIFS` is a single array `SUMPRODUCT` has nothing to multiply so it just sums the array

In short, when fed a single array `SUMPRODUCT` just sums the contents, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3})`  = 6

Comment: That was my guess but =sum(1,2,3) can also do the same. However, for the sumifs function, when the result is a single array like that, I cannot use =sum(sumifs(........)) to do the same trick. It's also gonna be 0.

Comment: No, I covered that in my answer - SUM is arguably preferable (because all you want is a SUM) but if you use SUM then your formula needs to be "array entered" using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: When I ctrl shift enter, the formula adds brackets on two sides. But if I add them on manually, it's not working. Why?

Comment: Yep, that’s the way it works - you always need to use the key combination - see this link https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Answer (score 2):

SumProduct is a very particular formula and you'll see it used in many occasions as a workaround to using array formulas, but only when it's used as a substitute of a point-array formulas (array formulas entered into a single cell), because it works with arrays by default.
In your particular case, you seem to get 0 with SUM(SUMIFS) as pure coincidence, because the sum of elements that are true for the first element of your array criterion is 0.

If you have, for example, a table as such:

```
A    B    C
1    t    t
2    f    f
3    t
4    x
5    x
```

and use the formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,$C$1:$C$2))
```

You will get `4` as a result, because it will only evaluate the first element of your condition array. If you instead enter it as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will evaluate the condition with all the elements of your conditional array, working as such:

1. Evaluate `=SUMIFS({1,2,3,4,5},{t,f,t,x,x},{t})`
2. Return `=SUM({1,2,3,4,5}*{1,0,1,0,0}) => SUM({1,0,3,0,0}) => 4`
3. Store `4` in the first position of the temporary array `{4,NULL}`
4. Evaluate `=SUMIFS({1,2,3,4,5},{t,f,t,x,x},{f})`
5. Return `=SUM({1,2,3,4,5}*{0,1,0,0,0}) => SUM({0,2,0,0,0}) => 2`
6. Store `2` in the second position of the temporary array `{4,2}`
7. Evaluate `=SUM({4,2})`
8. Return `6`

Which is pretty much the exact same thing the SUMPRODUCT formula would do.
Let me know if there's any further clarification needed.

Comment: Nice answer Fernando!

Comment: Note that if you use 
 `=SUM(SUMIFS($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,$C$1:$C$2))` without array entry then the result you actually see isn't necessarily the result of the first element - it depends `where` you put the formula - so for your example if the formula is in row 1 you see 4 as the result, if in row 2 you see 2, on any other row you see zero

Comment: ....and one more "wrinkle". If the "array" used for the criteria is an "array constant", e.g. if you use this version: `=SUM(SUMIFS($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,{"t","f"}))` then that works OK without array entry

Comment: You're right - I'd edit the answer but I'd pretty much copy+paste your first comment onto it, so that wouldn't be particuarly relevant. Regarding your second comment, that works because when you enter the criteria as an array constant, you are effectively already telling Excel to treat it as an array by definition, but yeah that's good to know as an alternate method.